# Single-word antonym for "cheapest"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, degree-of-comparison

I've been doing a translation for an article and it occured to me that I don't know a one-word antonym for the word 'cheapest'. 
I tried googling it, and the best suggestion I got was 'expensive', but that's not right since '*the most* expensive' is the proper antonym. And it's not a one-word antonym!
I understand that it's how the degrees of comparison work with different words, but is there really no direct one-word antonym?

The context is:

> After an aesthetic surgery, Lette becomes a success model that is unanimously accepted by the consumerist society in which everything is for sale, and the prettiest package sells _______ (antonym of 'cheapest')

It's from a commentary describing a play by Marius von Mayenburg (Der Hässliche (The Ugly One) in case anyone is interested).

Comment: From now on, I'm gonna say _expensivest_.

Comment: i really like "...and the prettiest package sells."  I don't think you need anything after that.

Comment: If you really want to fill in the blank after the word _sells,_ you need an adverb. You are getting answers with adjectives instead.

Comment: Why does it need to be one word? It's perfectly acceptable to translate English potato into French pomme de terre (apple of the earth). Or just about *every* German compound word (like Donaudampfschifffahrtgesellschaftskapitänskajütentürschlüssel) into a language where you're not allowed to endlessy string individual words together to form a single word :-) I would just use "for the highest price".

Comment: You could also say "best," which works really well here. What you're trying to do wouldn't work without restructuring the sentence. "The prettiest package is costliest" works; but "The prettiest package sells costliest" does not, because "costliest" is not an adverb. Neither is *any* antonym for "cheapest," since cheapest itself is an adjective.

Comment: I might also consider "is sold to the highest bidder." This may not be the most direct translation, but it is the most idiomatic. It also employs parallel construction with the "everything is..." construction.

Comment: @jpaugh The word _cheap_ has a definition as an adverb, meaning "for a low price," as in _they're selling cheap._ It doesn't seem much of a stretch to use _cheapest_ to mean "for the lowest price." But I think you're right about the antonyms--as far as I can tell, every word I have seen offered in a list of antonyms of _cheap_ has been an antonym of the adjective.

Comment: How about doubleplusuncheap? Okay, just kidding! Dearest (as mentioned by @Artemisia would be my bet.

Comment: "Prettiest" is a superlative, so to me, another superlative should follow. If it weren't just one word, I would say "the prettiest package sells for the most."

Comment: I wouldn't use 'dearest' in this context. Instead I'd say something like "Following cosmetic surgery, Lette becomes a successful model, universally coveted by a consumerist society in which everything is for sale, and in which the prettiest package commands the highest bid."

Comment: I'd be inclined to rephrase as "...fetches the most" or "...commands the highest price" or "...can set its own price". That doesn't really answer the question as asked, though, I admit.

Comment: @DavidK. Expensivestly

Comment: @Zano depending on the tone of the your writing, using an incorrect superlative can actually be pretty helpful. It's often seen as humorous and the "mistake" draws attention to what you're trying to say. Plus it's a rule that's broken on accident rarely enough that most people will realize you don't genuinely think that "awesomest," "expensivest" or "incorrectest" are real words.

Comment: @MadPhysicist For humorous effect, sure! For something closer to actual grammatical English, you might write _most expensively,_ although I think "verb + _expensively_" really means "verb + spending a lot of money while doing it." We don't necessarily expect to spend a lot of money while _selling_ the prettiest package; rather, we expect someone to spend a lot of money while _buying_ it. In light of that, I think _expensivestly_ might actually work better, since then it's clear that you're making up a definition of a word.

Comment: If this were my own writing, and not humorously intended, rather than "sells ____" I think I would write "fetches the highest price."

Comment: @DavidK Sure. Technically, cheapest won't fit any more than expensivest, and cheapestly is not a word either unfortunately. It would have to be most cheaply, which actually somewhat invalidates this entire question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I disagree about _cheapest._ In the phrase _sell cheap,_ the word _cheap_ is an adverb, and adverbs generally can be made superlative by appending _-est._ I wouldn't normally write _sell cheaply_ when I meant "sell at a low price," because _cheaply_ has too much connotation of "badly" or "shoddily done."

Comment: And @Zano demonstrates exactly how the English language has become what it is today ;)

Comment: There must be a lot of bored computer programmers on Stack Exchange, people who enjoy simple brain teasers such as this one. Otherwise, I cannot explain why this question is still on the Hot Question Network, and why three answers have earned over 100 upvotes. Three gold badges earned for three different answers is, I'm guessing,  a first

Comment: "model that is" should be "model who is"

Answer (score 165):

***Priciest*** - most pricey!

*...and the prettiest package is the priciest.*
(alliteration as a bonus!)

Not in the OED but common in my experience, and covered in both British English (Collins) and American English (Merriam-Webster) dictionaries:

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/priciest

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Priciest

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/priciest

Answer (score 159):

In **British** English, "dearest" is a word which is a direct antonym of "cheapest":

> **Dearest**
>
> 2. *British* Most expensive.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dearest)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54661/discussion-on-answer-by-artemisia-single-word-antonym-for-cheapest).

Comment: In AME I would expect not only for people to not get the intended meaning but to also infer that it is the _best_ or your _favorite_.

Comment: I was about to go with that one

Answer (score 127):

You could use **'costliest'**.

> ... and the prettiest package is the **costliest** one.

Adjective: Costly

Comparative: Costlier

Superlative: Costliest

When you are looking for similar words, you can find synonyms/antonyms on websites like [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/more+expensive) or [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/expensive) etc, and use its superlative (or any required form).
For more insight on how to make superlatives, check out [degree of comparison of adjectives](http://www.worldclasslearning.com/english/adjective-degrees-of-comparison.html).

However, please mind the context while using such word-for-word lookup. [Please see @Luke Sawczak's comment below.]

Comment: Could you possibly add a source/reference to this nice answer? That would greatly add to its value.

Comment: Because the OP is not a native speaker, and not everyone who uses or visits this website is a native speaker, it *is* therefore good practice to cite a reference, and provide a link.

Comment: This is absolutely the first word that came to my mind, and to me the most reasonable answer thus far.

Comment: @Mari-LouA made the changes!

Comment: Note that "costly" doesn't necessarily imply financial cost. For example, given our context of plastic surgery, a badly done inexpensive operation may be more costly than a well-done expensive operation.

Answer (score 18):

As an antonym out of context, costliest is probably best. It sounds a little odd to my ear to say "sells costliest" though. I would go for "sells highest" instead.

[high](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/high)

> 2.1 Of large numerical or monetary value.

Sample quotations from Google Books:

> "The Hannchen appears to be a slightly better average yielder, while
>   the Smyrna produces a better quality of grain and better yields in the
>   very dry seasons when grain sells highest."
>
> "Washboiler copper sells highest, and old brass coins and medals sell
>   very high."
>
> "It's the wellbred stuff that puts on the nicest finish and sells
>   highest on the market."

Comment: This is what I had planned on suggesting as soon as I had read the question :).

Comment: As a single word, *highest* probably requires too much context to make it clear the intended meaning is "most valuable". e.g. "Which of these is highest?" would probably be confusing without adding "...in price, I mean."

Comment: @talrnu Without context I would agree with you: highest is too ambiguous. To be clear: I'm suggesting it for this specific case, not as a single word antonym for "cheapest" in general.

Comment: I think this is a fine answer. The question specifically asked for a word to fill in the blank after _sells_ in "sells ____." The phrase _sells highest_ provides plenty of context for the reader to understand that _highest_ refers to price and not to the distance from the ground below.

Comment: Of your three quotes, only one has enough context to establish 'sells highest' isn't meant in the sense of 'highest seller'. In the first you can work out that it doesn't mean more grain is sold when it's dry, but coming across the other two I'd assume the second meant the seller sold more copper, and that 'wellbred stuff' sells better.

Answer (score 16):

1) As a few of the others point out, "priciest", "costliest", and "dearest" (highly regional in the sense of "most expensive") are good antonyms of "cheapest".

2) As einpoklum points out, however, "cheapest" would not be a typical adjective in this construction. ("He sells them cheap" is rather familiar for what could also be rendered "He sells them cheaply", "at a cheap price", or what have you.) The likelihood of finding another adjective that can be used in this unusual way is low, which is why some people are proposing things like "best" and "most". Those work syntactically but unfortunately have nothing to do with price without a few extra words of context.

3) As paxdiablo points out, by far the most important observation to be made here is that there is no reason whatsoever to translate one word in the source language to one word in the target language. You are guaranteed to produce a bad translation if you follow such a rule dogmatically, because languages are not 1:1 codes of each other's words!

As an occasional translator, I recommend going for a paraphrase — even if it ends up being a couple more words than you expect — rather than trying to cram the meaning into one word.

My suggestion: "...the prettiest package sells for the most" or "...for the highest price". An option for an idiomatic expression — in fact, probably the most apt cliché in a sentence like this — is "fetches": "...the prettiest package fetches the highest price."

Alternatively, as has also been suggested, if you take away the verb "sells" in favour of the copula "is", you can use an adjective like "priciest" or "costliest" (although in my estimation neither term's nuance is quite right for the passage). This of course requires breaking the one-word rule anyway and changing the structure of the sentence, so I don't see much of an advantage.

---

Incidentally, use "*who* is unanimously accepted" instead of "*that* is unanimously accepted", or simply delete "that is".

Edit: And see Mari-Lou A's note below as long as we're proofreading translations! To resolve "success" model, I assume you want "successful model", but without seeing the source it's hard to know exactly if that's what was meant.

Comment: Well then if you're nitpicking perfectly valid responses you had better mention that  "aesthetic surgery" is normally called *cosmetic surgery* in English, and "*Lette becomes a success model*" is ungrammatical.

Comment: Good catch! I'll incorporate those into the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The premise is flawed, in my view.

The package sells "cheapest" would be more correctly stated as "sells most cheaply" or "the package is the cheapest".  Or "the package is the least expensive (of all the packages)".

You could say "the package **is** the cheapest (package)", in which case saying it is the most expensive would be "the package is the costliest/dearest (package)".

Answer (score 7):

"Priciest" and "costliest" are adjectives describing the item that is most expensive. "Steepest" describes the highest price itself, though this word may have a negative connotation. Apologies if this isn't precisely what you're looking for, but these are all that come to mind.

Comment: This answers has already been given.

Comment: Given is is an English Stack, then: (*answer) or (*have). 
Also: there is always room for another good suggestion, such as this one.

Comment: Don't forget *these if you use *have.

Comment: "Priciest" and "costliest" have already been suggested; "steepest" isn't appropriate because, as you say, it applies only to the price, whereas the question is looking for a word to describe the thing bought for that price.

Comment: Much as these are good antonyms for "cheapest", none of them can complete this particular sentence with much coherence.

Comment: steepest isn't a good suggestion. This should be removed to not confuse our nonnative English speaking friends. Or enhanced.

Comment: Steepest also holds negative connotations. Something to note.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Good point! I'll note that in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Although **costliest** and **priciest** serve as the direct antonym of the word, however, in case you would like to take a look at another option, then the following should help:

**prettiest package commands a fortune.**

**[Command](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/command)**

> to deserve and get something good, such as attention, respect, or a lot of money

In case of **fortune**, I probably do not need to add a citation.

As pointed out by another reader, using the verb command, which offers a better alternative to the overused auxiliary, the author could also rewrite the sentence as follows:

> - The prettiest package commands the highest price.

Comment: Neither of those are a single word antonym for cheapest.

Comment: @JMac: Disinterested is presenting an *option* to antonym that "solves" the question.

Comment: @M.Mat it doesn't solve the question.  The question specifically said a single word request, they even gave an example for a multiple word answer, so clearly they didn't require anything besides a single word answer.  If someone requests a single word it isn't really correct to present them with a 2 word option.  If there were no single words to represent it then that could be outlined in an answer, but we already know that's not the case.  This answer doesn't even suggest it is the most expensive, just relatively expensive, so it is very incorrect.

Comment: Being that the question is misguided, this is a helpful answer. It's much more important to produce good "English language & usage" than to follow the question to a T. However, despite the added naturalness of "commands a fortune", it is missing the superlative nuance that would match "prettiest" both grammatically and stylistically, so I wouldn't settle on this answer exactly.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I'd argue that this answer isn't particularly helpful.  The term he defined was "commands" which is completely irrelevant in this context and just happens to work when referring to a fortune.  I'd say to a non-English speaker it may even be detrimental, as it implies that the phrase "commands a fortune" is more common than "is expensive".  It seemed like they purposefully obscured the phrase more than necessary.

Comment: @JMac Agreed — at the end of the day it's not what was needed. But it does have the advantage of giving an alternative in good English, which can at least be a starting point for what *is* a useful method: dropping the idea that the syntax must match exactly and searching for a natural idiom in the target language.

Comment: @JMac: Apologies for the late response. Considering that I had started that response by explicitly declaring that you, the person asking the question, already have the direct antonyms, I would like to suggest an alternative that despite not meeting the criterion, in my opinion, finishes off the statement rather well. Despite what the other person has said, an opinion which he has articulated quite well, I still consider the alternative a better option: subjective opinion.

Comment: @Disinterested But it isn't one word **or** an antonym.  "Commanding a fortune" is not the opposite of "cheapest" or "worth the least", it is the antonym of "cheap" or "worth little", but the antonym was a request for the word that means "most cheap" while your response does not represent that.  It is also a highly uncommon way to say that in modern English, so stylistically it doesn't fit in well.

Comment: As I have seen people accept phrases as answer to single word requests, hence I did not consider that an issue; I still do not consider that an issue, as it remains that person’s choice. When it comes to style, well, considering that “worth nothing” would translate into being completely free, hence what else would one be left with after the item that costs little? In my experience so far, I have neither read nor heard the phrase “worth littlest”.

Comment: Using "command" as an optional phrasing, I like "the prettiest package commands the prettiest price."

Comment: @Pooneil Thank you for liking just a part of the suggestion. Although it does not qualify as a single word suggestion in the strictest sense, as another commentator has pointed out, however, such suggestions can serve a purpose in providing the author or other users with another idea or an alternative construction. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest *premium*, which is defined as follows by [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/premium):

> **premium** *[as a modifier]* Relating to or denoting a commodity or product of superior quality and therefore a higher price.

In the provided context, it would be "for a premium", which uses the slightly different definition of "a sum added to an ordinary price or charge."

Comment: Hi, chad. Your suggestion seems very reasonable to me, so I can only conclude that the downvoter objected to your not including a source and link to the definitions you quote in your answer. I have supplied these and given you an upvote—but in future posts at English Language & Usage, please identify your sources in your answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> After an aesthetic surgery, Lette becomes a success model that is
>   unanimously accepted by the consumerist society in which everything is
>   for sale, and the prettiest package sells _______

That foreign syntax needs more than one word, maybe:

> After his plastic surgery, Lette becomes a star unanimously admired
>   in a consumerist society where everything is for sale, and the
>   prettiest package profits most.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `highest`, due to the context `sells ____`, it would be understood that you are talking about the price. Compare the expression "buys low and sells high". Alternatively you can use `highest-priced`.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, there's an problem with that question (not in OP's question - in the one OP is quoting). You cannot reasonably, IMHO, fill in an antonym of 'cheapest' and properly complete that sentence. It should be:

> ... and the prettiest package sells **best**.

or

> ... and the prettiest package sells **most**.

Comment: The OP is doing a translation, he wants to to be faithful to the original text, and the non-native author uses the term "most expensive" in his/her article. A best-selling product does not mean or imply it is expensive, quite the opposite in fact. Very often the products that sell the most are the ones considered best value for money. Eliminate the verb *sell* and you have `the prettiest package is the most expensive` which makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

*Choicest* also works here, in a slightly more indirect way than some of the other suggestions.

Comment: "The prettiest package sells choicest" is gobbledegook.

Comment: Fair point - answers the question but doesn't fit this context.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind **dearest** sounds best. Costliest and priciest sound a bit clumsy to my ear (dare I say it ... American) I would use **most costly** rather than say **costliest**  and then it is no longer a one word antonym. **Dearest** would be used through out the English speaking world, except America.

Answer (score -1):

...the prettiest package sells **extravagantly**

Would make sense, however the word extravagant doesn't always refer to the price of something, it suggests that the item is a luxury that most people cannot afford.