# More neutral way of saying expensive

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to re-word the title of a list;

Most Expensive Patients

So it doesn't sound like there is a negative burdensome connotation with the word Expensive i.e. it's not their fault they have the highest costs associated with them. I have tried "Most Costliest Patients" but that too doesn't feel right, is there a word I can substitute for Expensive that is more neutral.

Comment: Is it the patients that are expensive or the cost(s)  of their treatment?

Comment: @Clare the cost of their treatment

Comment: 'Neediest' probably gets it across.

Comment: Neediest lacks the element of cost and infers a judgement that I am not qualified to make.

Comment: Since you're happy to say *it's not their fault they have the **highest costs** associated with them,* what's wrong with just assigning them to the ***High Cost*** category? Or ***Resource-intensive*** if you want to distance yourself further from "financial" yardsticks.

Comment: @Edwin: Given one patient about to die from dehydration, and another needing a hip replacement, I'd say the first one was the "neediest" (he ***really*** needs urgent attention!), even though the cost of his glass of water would be nugatory compared to the cost of the operation (which it wouldn't be the end of the world if it were delayed or even cancelled).

Comment: You're probably forced into 'those patients whose treatment requires the greatest expenditure', if you're not happy with a less strict formulation.

Comment: @FF Hence the way I couched the response. 'Neediest' interpreted as 'needing the most expensive treatments' would possibly work in some contexts. Obviously, disambiguation would often be necessary.

Comment: Patients with highest associated cost?

Comment: Note that "most costliest" is wrong. It's either "most costly" or "costliest," not both.

Comment: [Single-word antonym for “cheapest”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375905/single-word-antonym-for-cheapest) if I cast my vote to close it as a duplicate, it will happen immediately. So... let someone either write an answer or VTC with a single non-binding vote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single-word antonym for "cheapest"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375905/single-word-antonym-for-cheapest)

Comment: @Mari-LouA why are you so eager to close? The question is perfectly valid in my opinion.

Comment: @Stefan I haven't closed anything. I haven't cast any vote to close. I am not eager to close, on the contrary. If I were it would be closed now because I have the dupe-hammer.

Comment: Are these your most profitable patients or are they your lowest margin pAtients?

Answer (score 3):

the most ***resource-intensive*** patients

This is a less crass way of saying the most expensive patients, because it conjures up a mental picture of devoted people spending time with patients rather than money being spent on patients.

The result is the same, of course. All these highly skilled people must be paid for their time. Resource-intensive patients require a lot of attention from doctors, physician's assistants, nurses, technicians, therapists, nursing assistants, dieticians and aides, and also usually require many tests, high-tech monitoring and lots of medicines.  All of this is expensive.

The results can be miraculous.

A resource-intensive task is one that requires a lot of resources, often but not always over a limited period of time.  *Resource*, from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/resource):

> a source of supply, support, or aid, especially one that can be
>   readily drawn upon when needed.